# ADF Create Pipeline Run - Parameters

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to trigger a ADF Pipeline via REST API and pass a parameter in order to execute the pipeline for the given ID (parameter).
With sparse documentation around this, I am unable to figure out how to pass parameters to the URL

Sample:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/asdc57878-77fg-fb1e8-7b06-7b0698bfb1e8/resourceGroups/dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/df-datafactory-dev/pipelines/pl_StartProcessing/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01
```

I tried to send parmaters in the request body but I get the following message depending on how params are sent

```
{
    "message": "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource."
}
```

I tried using python requests :

```
import requests

url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/adsad-asdasd-adasd-adasda-adada/resourceGroups/dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datafactory-dev/pipelines/pl_Processing/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01"

payload = " \"parameters\": {\r\n     “stateID”: “78787878”\r\n}"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer adsasdasdsad'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

I tried to put the parameter in the payload (body)

Comment: Which parameter do you want to use? The `given ID` you mean `referencePipelineRunId`? Could you show your complete request sample, Including the body?

Comment: The pipeline expects Stateid as a parameter. This is a custom pipeline parameter instead of a URI parameter

Comment: Could you update your question with the sample request you have tried?

Comment: Added sample code. It is python based.

Comment: @JoyWang any suggestions on this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Paramters can be passed within body

python sample:

```
import requests

url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/adsad-asdasd-adasd-adasda-adada/resourceGroups/dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datafactory-dev/pipelines/pl_Processing/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01"

payload = "{\"stateID\":1200}"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer adsasdasdsad'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a parameter name as post

```
url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/adsad-asdasd-adasd-adasda-adada/resourceGroups/dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datafactory-dev/pipelines/pl_Processing/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01 -d '{"stateID"="78787878"}'
```

microsoft docs for your reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass them as the POST body.
To pass more than one parameter the body this looks like:

```
{
```

"param1": "param1value"
,"param2":"param2value"
}